# Pandas Datetime column Filtering Issue when using variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to filter a pandas column based on the date in one of my dataframe columns. So for example I have one column called 'Date', that has been converted to datetime using

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Placing it in the format 2019-06-01 for example. Now I can perform a filter on the column, so if I wanted to get dates only in June I could do

```
df[(df['Date'] >= '2019-06-01') & (df['Date'] <= '2019-06-30')]
```

And this works just fine, comparing the datetime to a string, which I assume pandas converts to a datetime automatically to perform the comparison.

However, this stops working as soon as I assign the comparison string to a variable, so if I do this

```
start = '2019-06-01'
end = '2019-06-30'
df[(df['Date'] >= start) & (df['Date'] <= end)]
```

I get an error: TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and str

Any ideas on why this may be occurring?

Comment: The error suggests that of the two columns being compared, one has type string while the other has type datetime. So there's probably an entry in one of the columns that makes it cast to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use *Pandas* version *0.25* and *Python* version *3.7.0*.

I checked your code:

```
start = '2019-06-01'
end = '2019-06-30'
df[(df['Date'] >= start) & (df['Date'] <= end)]
```

getting proper result (no error).

If you use some older version of either *Python* or *Pandas*, consider upgrading them.

I checked also other variants of code:

1. Conversion of "border" values to *datetime*:

   ```
   d1 = pd.to_datetime('2019-06-01')
   d2 = pd.to_datetime('2019-06-30')
   df[df.Date.between(d1, d2)]
   ```
2. Usage of *between* with both arguments as *string*s:

   ```
   df[df.Date.between('2019-06-01', '2019-06-30')]
   ```

getting also **proper result**. Check them on your installation
as it is now and after upgrade (if you decide to do it).